# Cannot use MAX() in a prepared mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm using the last version of PHP 5 and MySQL.

The query is the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT max(num) 
    FROM list
    WHERE value = ?";
```

If I manually substitute the value with the value: `$my_value` and I execute from phpMyAdmin the query I obtain the correct result.

Instead, if I prepare the query in this way, I don't obtain anything:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $my_value);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($num);
$stmt->close();
echo "Num: [" . $num . "]";
```

The output is: `Num: []`

Comment: I believe you still need to `fetch` with `bind_result`, I don't use mysqli often though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind_result()` does not remove the need to call the `fetch()` command. Your code should look something like:

```php
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $my_value);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($num);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
echo "Num: [" . $num . "]";
```

See the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) for more info on that.

Comment: It was a so elementary thing! Thank you, I think that I need a pause :)